# Llamar a metodo dentro de otro

Tags: java

tengo un problema a la hora de llamar al otro método. Hice un método para no estar haciendo mucho código. Pero a la hora de llamar al otro método no me funciona. 
matrizButaca = muestraMatriz(); 
Mas que todo tengo mi problema ahí, no se porque no se están llamando, si pueden ayudarme se los agradecería demasiado.
En el IDE me tira esto: reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
    // Declaracion de VARIABLES.
    int menuTeatroOpciones;

    //Declaración matriz principal
    char matrizButaca[][] = new char [5][22];
    matrizButaca = muestraMatriz();
    do
    { // Inicio DO.

        System.out.println("*************\n"+"MENU\n"+"*************\n"+"[1] Mostrar butacas\n"+"[2] Registrar reserva\n"+
        "[3] Registrar venta de butacas\n"+"[4] Anular venta de butacas\n"+"[5] Mostrar resumen de butacas\n"+"[6] Salir\n");
        menuTeatroOpciones = sc.nextInt();

        switch(menuTeatroOpciones){ // Inicio SWITCH.
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Butacas disponibles: ");
                muestraMatrizPrincipal(matrizButaca);
                break;
            case 2:
                muestraRegistrarReserva(matrizButaca);
                break;
            System.out.println("Adiós ");
            break;*/

            default:
                System.out.println("Opción de menú INCORRECTA.");
                break;
        } // Fin SWITCH.
    }while(menuTeatroOpciones != 2);

} // Fin segundo.

// Inicio de METODOS.
public static void muestraMatriz(char matriz [][]){ // Inicio METODO.
    for(int f = 0 ; f < matriz.length ; f++){ // Inicio FOR.
        for(int c = 0 ; c < matriz[f].length ; c++){ // Inicio FOR.

            matriz[f][c]= 'L';
            matriz[f][5] = 'P';
            matriz[f][16] = 'P';
        } // Fin FOR.

    } // Fin FOR.

} // Fin METODO.


// Metodo que abarca todo

public static void muestraMatrizPrincipal(char matriz [][]){ // Inicio METODO

    for(int f = 0 ; f < matriz.length ; f++){
        for(int c = 0 ; c < matriz[f].length ; c++){
            System.out.print(matriz[f][c]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}// Fin METODO.
```

Comment: No es porque te falta enviarle los parámetros a tu método?, en la llamada no le pasas nada pero en el método si que pides

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de llamar a `muestraMatriz()` sin parámetros y además tratando de asignárselo al `Array` de tipo `char` `matrizButaca[][]` que ya está inicializado anteriormente en la siguiente línea.

```java
char matrizButaca[][] = new char [5][22]; // creado e inicializado en la misma línea
```

El error:

> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Se podría traducir a que, la cantidad de parámetros que estás tratando de pasar a un método, no coinciden con la cantidad de parámetros que este recibe de acuerdo a como fue construido.

---

Es debido a que estás tratando de llamar a un método sin pasar ningún parámetro:

```java
matrizButaca = muestraMatriz(); //llamada al método sin ningún parámetro
```

Pero cuando creaste el método `muestraMatriz()` este recibe `Array` de tipo `char` como parámetro:

```java
public static void muestraMatriz(char matriz [][]){...} //recibe un parámetro
```

Para que el método trabaje con el `Array` matrizButaca, debes de mandarla como parámetro, no tratar de asignarlo.

```java
muestraMatriz(matrizButaca); // array pasado como parámetro
```

Comment: No me funciono me salio algo como esto: error: cannot find symbol / error: illegal start of type

Comment: en que parte del código lanza ese error?

Comment: C:\Users\Roger\Desktop\CUC\Cuatrimestre 2\programacion 1\Proyecto\ReservaTeatro.java:18: error: illegal start of type
  matrizButaca = (muestraMatriz);
                 ^

Comment: La línea debería de ser muestraMatriz(matrizButaca);  llamas al método muestraMatriz y le pasas como parámetro matriaButaca,